# getJSONArray wrong format for {"GetProdByBizResult":{"TotalCount":4,"RootResults":[{....}]}}"

Tags: android, json, wcf

I successfully get data from wcf web service in my android studio app.
I get this format for the json response.

```
{"GetProdByBizResult":{"TotalCount":4,"RootResults":[{"catId":1348,"catOrder":1,...
```

what is the parameter that has to be provide in order to convert it to JSONArray ?

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("RootResults");//this doesn't work
```

I found a workaround by replacing my json string to "RootResults":[{"....}]}"
then

```
jsonResponse.getJSONArray("RootResults");
```

is working perfect

Comment: Can you please share your code here so i can understand what did you have completed?

Comment: `JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("GetProdByBizResult").getJSONArray("RootResults");` try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "GetProdByBizResult": {
    "TotalCount": 4,
    "RootResults": [
      {
        "catId": 1348,
        "catOrder": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Json array "RootResults" is a part of json object "GetProdByBizResult" so we need to take "GetProdByBizResult" josn object first and then from this object you can fetch the "RootResults" json array, like

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("GetProdByBizResult");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("RootResults");
```